# calculate BACKLOG Y-1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calculating backlog y-1 . I Use the value of BACKLOG_M corresponding to the Snapdate of the first of the month -12. 
For example: for each Snapdate of January 2018, we retrieve the value of the Snapdate 1st of February 2017.
[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pp2T.png)

I tried the following script but it returns errors values [stg].[CMA_SALES_KPI] and dbo.CMA_SALES_KPI_Daily contains periods dates. Data_Bckl contains the value of backlog for each date.

```
SELECT     T22.ANNE, T22.MOIS, T3.BCKL AS BCK3
FROM        (
select
        convert(nvarchar(6), dateadd(month, - 11, convert(datetime, SNAP)), 112)           as PERI,
        year(SNAP)                                                                            as ANNE,
        month(SNAP)                                                                           as MOIS
      from
        [stg].[CMA_SALES_KPI]
      where
        day(SNAP) = 1
      union
      select
        convert(nvarchar(6), dateadd(month, - 11, dateadd(month, -1, min(SNAPDATE))), 112) as PERI,
        min([YEAR])                                                                           as ANNE,
        min([MONTH])                                                                          as MOIS
      from
        dbo.CMA_SALES_KPI_Daily
) AS T22 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Data_Bckl AS T3 ON CONVERT(nvarchar(6), T3.SNAP, 112) = T22.PERI
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join using the first of the month and the 1 year previous as the condition:

```
select t1.*, t2.backlog_m
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2
  on DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, t1.snap), 0) -- first of this month
     = dateadd(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, t2.snap), 0))  -- first of this month last year
```

Comment: I need to retrive the value of 1st of the month rolling back 12 months

Comment: @testtest Instructions (incredibly) unclear. Edit your question to include sample data and expected result.